# Play Async Vs Akka Actor

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework, akka, actor

I'm new to both Play framework and Akka Toolkit.

We are trying to build an orchestration layer between the web client and microservices using Play. 
So basically for every request from the client, Play has to do a WS call and return the JSON (as well as cache it).

Now when doing the WS call, we can use Play Async APIs or use Akka actors.
**Does one of these options outweigh the other anyway?**

Is there any recommendation on when one should venture into using Akka actors along with Play compared to directly using Play Async APIs?

Comment: what is Play Async API, exactly? Please provide a web reference. There are different async solutions used in Play.

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaAsync "Java 8 provides a generic promise API called CompletionStage. A CompletionStage<Result> will eventually be redeemed with a value of type Result. By using a CompletionStage<Result> instead of a normal Result, we are able to return from our action quickly without blocking anything. Play will then serve the result as soon as the promise is redeemed.

The web client will be blocked while waiting for the response, but nothing will be blocked on the server, and server resources can be used to serve other clients."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Akka, main notion as an actor, which is an object with memory to keep state. Sequential operations to that state are serialized by the system and cannot interfere. In Java8 promise/futures, main notion is asynchronous method call, and if different methods belong to the same object, it is user's responsibility to provide serial access - which is not easy and can be error prone.
Then, using futures implies creation of a `Future` object for each separate operation, which can be considered as overhead if the operations are fine-grained.
On the other hand, `CompletableFuture` has means to combine several events into one like `allOf()`, which has no direct analogue in Akka.